# continuous analogues of Newton's method

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, newton-method

Suppose we want to minimize some convex functional $J(u)$ where $u$ lives in some Banach space $V$.
The classical Newton method

$$\mathrm d^2J(u_n)(u_{n + 1} - u_n) = -\mathrm dJ(u_n)$$

can be viewed as an explicit Euler discretization of the dynamical system

$$\tau\;\mathrm d^2J(u)\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} = -\mathrm dJ(u),$$

that takes a constant timestep $\tau$ at every step.
You can think of a primitive damped Newton method as taking a timestep that is some fraction of $\tau$, and a globally-convergent Newton line search method as using a variable timestep that is tuned to make sure that the objective decreases.
Several papers have remarked on this (see below).

**Are there improved, practical solution methods based on viewing Newton's method as a dynamical system?**
For example, what happens if, instead of doing a line search at every iteration, you were to use a classical adaptive Runge Kutta method with stepsize control like RK-1/2 or similar?
More generally, is there some respect in which this dynamical systems viewpoint is practically relevant, or is it just a mathematical curiosity?

References:

- https://doi.org/10.1080/01630560802484294
- https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812792686_0012
- In Russian, but arguably the first: http://www.mathnet.ru/links/fec5f826de87c3778ef0ddea8e20b256/ivm2977.pdf

Comment: it's no longer relevant for practical solutions, but i remember a professor once told me that they used to solve nonlinear systems by realising the continuous system and letting it converge.

Comment: @ThijsSteel That would be a pseudo-timestepping approach to solving nonlinear problems. (As in "pseudo-time" stepping, not pseudo-"time stepping" -- it's an artificial time variable.)

Comment: I was involved in using an analog computing chip that used a continuous version of Newton's method Huang, Y., Guo, N., Seok, M., Tsividis, Y., Mandli, K., & Sethumadhavan, S. (2017). Hybrid analog-digital solution of nonlinear partial differential equations (pp. 665–678). https://doi.org/10.1145/3123939.3124550.

Comment: Thanks @KyleMandli, the citations there pointed me in the right direction! Also, that paper is totally insane and wonderful.

Comment: Was a fun paper to work on!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to use higher-order ODE integration methods on the Newton dynamical system to do better than vanilla Newton with some globalization strategy.
[Brezinski (2001)](https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/34/48/329) gives a negative result in Theorem 2 and the discussion after it, showing that only the explicit Euler scheme has superlinear convergence.